# Restricting the use of website outside of an office (or a particular computer)

Tags: php, database, security, authentication, networking

I have a website url which I don't want any computer to access except one or two computers. I only want certain employees' computer to access it. Is it possible?

Comment: I tried to restrict it with a router linksys but doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to restrict by the IP you can use the htaccess file
http://www.toshop.com/htaccess-generator.cfm

but keep in your mind that you have two choice:

1- allow these IP address and ban everyone else

2- ban these IP addresses and allow everyone else

Comment: Thanks. So should i just put that generated code in the web directory?

Comment: Moreover, if i am not wrong, my IP would be the one generated via google search "What is my IP"?

Comment: And how would i restrict via MAC address?

Comment: see this http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1118/can-i-block-based-on-mac-address